# SQlite запрос выводит только одну строку

Tags: java, android, dao, room

Есть две таблицы `Profile - id, idOrder и т.д.` и `Order - id, idBatch и т.д.` 
Задача вытянуть из таблицы `Profile` все данные по `idOrder`.
Из данного запроса выводится только первый элемент по `idBatch`, хотя в таблице `Order` их много.
Просьба помочь с запросом.

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM Profile WHERE idOrder == (SELECT id FROM `Order` WHERE idBatch = :idBatch) ")
  Single<List<Profile>> getAllByIdBatch(long idBatch);
```

Дополнение - цель запроса: выбрать все записи из таблицы Profile, в которых поле idOrder соответствует полю id таблицы Order в которой поле IdBatch соответствует заданному значению `getAllByIdBatch(long idBatch)`

Comment: @pavlofff `p.idOrder = r.idBatch` что то вы разные айдишники сравниваете. Тут же обычный join с условием `WHERE idBatch = :idBatch`

Comment: Цель запроса: выбрать все записи из таблицы Profile, в которых поле idOrder соответствует полю id таблицы Order в которой поле IdBatch соответствует заданному значению `getAllByIdBatch(long idBatch)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

должно быть

```
SELECT * FROM Profile WHERE idOrder in (SELECT id FROM `Order` WHERE idBatch = :idBatch)
```

Если использовать равенство, то он возьмет первую строку из подзапроса и будет сравнивать с ней. Вот вы и получили только одну строку в ответе

Comment: Большое спасибо! Работает так как и хотел!